# file preview without downloading it using express

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to develop a file management web app and I want to add an option to preview files before downloading it I'm using Node Js express, is there any way to implement that.
or just a small guide because I tried all the possible solutions on the net but it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can preview it, you just need to add declaration for your file path and you can access directly from url

```
const app = express();
const __dirname = path.resolve()
//public is the name of folder where your file is being stored
app.use("preview",express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public")));
```

So you can directly access the file using url `expressurl/preview/filename` and preview it wherever you want

Comment: but I think is not reasonable to set all the files as public, I want the user will be able to preview the file depending on his choice, like sending the file to the user and displaying them each time he clicks preview on a specific file

Comment: or can I move the file to the public directory after the page is loaded, is he will be accessible in the frontend even if I moved it after the page is loaded?

Comment: Yes it will be accessible if the file is present in the public directory like i explained, but in order to preview it you need to make sure that the file is moved before it is being accessed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in node filesystem module fs to read and write to files on the server. So in your case you want to read the content of files, so something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('my-file.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
});
```